# If the set is a complex linear space?

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

The set $P$ consists of complex trigonometric polynomials $$f_k(t)=\sum_{j=0}^k a_j e^{iτ_jt},$$ where $$ k\in \mathbb N, a_1,...,a_k \in \mathbb C, τ_1,...,τ_k \in  \mathbb R.$$

**Show that $P$ is a complex linear space.**

I have to show that $$f,g \in P, α, β \in \mathbb C \Rightarrow (αf+βg) \in P.$$

**My solution:**
$$(αf+βg)_k(t) = \sum_{j=0}^k (αa_j e^{iτ_jt} + βa_j e^{iτ_jt} ) =  \sum_{j=0}^k αa_j e^{iτ_jt} + \sum_{j=0}^k βa_j e^{iτ_jt} \\ = α\sum_{j=0}^k a_j e^{iτ_jt} + β\sum_{j=0}^k a_j e^{iτ_jt} = αf_k(t) + βg_k(t). $$
And it is true.

**Question:**
Is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes, it looks just fine...with a somewhat funny notation, but fine.

Comment: Well, I think the choice of $k$ and of $\tau_0,\tau_1,\dots,\tau_k$ varies.  That is, not all elements of $P$ use the same ones.